# Multiple type control in a generic c# function

Tags: c#, generics

In a class I have to implement a generic function whose declaration looks like this:

```
private async Task<T> ValidateWalletRequest<T>(string authToken, object objRequest, Wallet wallet)
    where T : DebitRequest
```

I need to be able to control more than one type per T. How can I do this? Thank you.